# changing/adding behavior of stl bitset<>::reference::operator=(int)

Tags: c++, stl

I need a bitset with a slightly diffrent behavior when asigning variables with integer type to a specific bit. The bit should be set to zero if the assigned integer is smaller then one, and to one elsewise.

As a simple solution I copied the STL bitset, replaced the classname with altbitset, adjusted namespaces and include guard and added following function under `reference& operator=(bool __x)` in the nested `reference` class:

```
template <typename T> 
reference& operator=(T i) {
    if (i<1) return operator=(false);
    return operator=(true);
}
```

It works as expected.

**Question is** if there is a better way doing this.

Comment: Why not just `bv[n] = (i < 1)`?

Comment: @GManNickG: That is the correct answer and should be posted as one! Copy/pasting the whole library to add a step to its inputs is .... bizarre.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Will do. :)

Comment: @crush: You mean function, or function template, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't copy a library just to add a new function. Not only that, the new function is wildly unintuitive and could possibly be the source of errors for even just *reading* the code, let alone writing it.

Before:

```
bv[n] = -1; // I know a Boolean conversion on -1 will take place
assert(bv[n]); // of course, since -1 as a Boolean is true
```

After:

```
bv[n] = -1; // I guess an integer < 1 means false?
assert(bv[n]); // Who changed my bitvector semantics?!
```

Just write it out so it makes sense in *your* domain:

```
bv[n] = (i < 1);
```

Remember: simplest doesn't always mean fewest characters, it means clearest to read.

---

If you *do* want to extend the functionality of existing types, you should do so with free functions:

```
template <typename BitSet, typename Integer>
auto assign_bit_integer(BitSet& bits, const std::size_t bit, const Integer integer) ->
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Integer>::value,
                            typename BitSet::reference>::type
{
    return bits[bit] = (integer < 1);
}
```

Giving:

```
std::bitset<8> bits;

assign_bit_integer(bits, 0, 5);
// ERROR: assign_bit_integer(bits, 0, 5.5);
```

But for such a small function with no clear "obvious" name that describes what it does concisely(`assign_bit_true_if_less_than_one_otherwise_false` is verbose, to say the least), just write out the code; it says the same thing anyway.

Comment: Did it with bv[n] = map(i) before. Liked to have it look "nicer". Thanks a lot!